# Is it possible to print (show in output or in a separate table) computed data in spss?

Tags: spss

I'm working with spss code. I'd like to print RXX result that was computed by spss to console(output file). Is there in spss any possible way to do this?

Code shown below:

```
COMPUTE R = CR. /* CR is default name of matrix */
COMPUTE N = NCOL(R). /* Number of variables */
COMPUTE RXX = R(2:N,2:N). /* Correlations between the X’s */
COMPUTE RXY = R(2:N,1). /* Correlations between Y and the X’s */
CALL EIGEN(RXX,EVEC,EV). /* Begin singular value decomposition */
COMPUTE D = MDIAG(EV). /* Diagonal matrix of eigenvalues */
COMPUTE DELTA = SQRT(D). /* Square root of eigenvalues */
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is within a `matrix - end matrix` sequence you can use the `PRINT` command in matrix syntax. For example:

```
print RXX /TITLE="these are my RXX results:".
```